# How to use OAuth from Android app and WCF webservices?

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, security, oauth

I am creating an Android application consuming WCF webservice. I was told that I can use OAuth to make the webservice secure.
What I would like to do is only authorized person can access the webservices without passing the username and password for every webservice request. The username and password will be provided upon login.
Can OAuth do what I want? If YES, please point me to some tutorials/references for:
1)How should I include OAuth in my webservice
2)How to use it from Android client.

Note: The app and webservice are in an intranet environment with **NO internet access**.

Comment: So if the webservice is in an **intranet** environment, I presume they'll only be able to access it from their Android devices when on Wifi (or vpn, or something similar)?

Comment: @Marvin There are a lot of other vendors in the intranet.

Comment: This are three questions and should be asked separately: How to use OAuth in WCF? How to use OAuth in Android? (I expect both will be answered by Google much faster). The last is how to make this work because as @Marvin stated this has some constraints and your comment absolutely not make it clear.

Comment: @Marvin It will be used via 3G with custom APN from telco.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka First of all, is it even suitable solution? Some people suggest some other things. May I know the constraints that you have mentioned?

Comment: May I know the reason of my question was down voted?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth will not help much in this matter. OAuth is a security protocol tipically used for delegating authorization, but you will have to pass the credentials at least one time to the service and establish some kind of security session using cookies or something similar. If you are in an intranet scenario, you might want to use some other kind of authentication like X509 certificates altough I am not sure if it is supported in android.

Pablo.

Comment: Did you mean that to get the token, I must connect at least one time to the internet?